# Writing a pairwise function that compares difference between categorical variables that can be passed to add_stat from gt_summary package

Tags: r, function, gtsummary

This is a question posted in 2021 on Github https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/790.

I'm beginner in creating customized functions. I was wondering if anybody can help me come up with a function that tests the difference between categorical variables that can be passed through the `add_stat` function in `gtsummary` package. The following function is for numeric variables.

```
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.3.6.9013'
library(tidyverse)


# define a pairwise test in the gtsummary format to calculate pairwise p-values
gts_pairwise.t.test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  pairwise.t.test(data[[variable]], data[[by]]) %>% 
    broom::tidy() %>%
    mutate(label = glue::glue("**{group2} vs. {group1}**")) %>%
    select(label, p.value) %>%
    spread(label, p.value)
}

# test function
gts_pairwise.t.test(trial, "age", "grade")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   `**I vs. II**` `**I vs. III**` `**II vs. III**`
#>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1              1               1                1

trial %>%
  select(age, marker, grade) %>%
  # create summary table split by Grade
  tbl_summary(
    by = grade,
    missing = "no",
    statistic = everything() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) %>%
  # add pairwise comparisons
  add_stat(fns = everything() ~ gts_pairwise.t.test) %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(c('**I vs. II**', '**I vs. III**', '**II vs. III**') ~ style_pvalue) %>%
  # convert to kable to display on github
  as_kable()

|**Characteristic**   | **I**, N = 68 | **II**, N = 68 | **III**, N = 64 | **I vs. II** | **I vs. III** | **II vs. III** |
|:--------------------|:-------------:|:--------------:|:---------------:|:------------:|:-------------:|:--------------:|
|Age                  |    46 (15)    |    48 (14)     |     48 (14)     |     >0.9     |     >0.9      |      >0.9      |
|Marker Level (ng/mL) |  1.07 (0.89)  |  0.68 (0.73)   |   1.00 (0.92)   |    0.031     |      0.6      |     0.079      |
```

I would appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!!!